# how to delete the header in one page?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

How do I delete the "chapitre 4" at the top of the page?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Try `\thispagestyle{empty}` on that page. If this does not help, please add a minimal working example that shows what you are doing.

Comment: Or, if you do not want remove completely the header and  footer, but only the  "Chapter 4" part, run  `texdoc fancyhdr`.

Comment: @Fran I do not understand you. Can you explain me a little? because I am a beginner

Comment: @KarimKHAN You should have a program named  `texdoc` to search latex documentation related with the term of search, so  `texdoc fancyhdr` will show you the PDF manual of the `fancyhdr` package. If you do not have `texdoc` installed, you can also reach this manual in   http://www.texdoc.net/ or  https://www.ctan.org/, but the first is faster.

Comment: @Fran Thank you sir

Comment: @Fran texdoc is not only for latex documentation. All documentation concerned to TeX and friends is accessible by it.

Comment: @wipet I had already assumed that by the program name :)

Comment: @KarimKHAN BTW, I don't realize the `memoir` tag. From `texdoc memoir`: "The memoir class includes the functionality of many packages, for instance the tocloft
package for controlling the table of contents or methods similar to the fancyhdr package for designing your own headers.". See the chapter of page 107.

Comment: @Fran `memoir` provides its own methods for pagestyles (headers and footers). Best not to use the `fancyhdr` package with `memoir`.

Comment: @PeterWilson Yes, and that's why my  comment above yours have sense. Right?